# What is the effect of a row of zeros in singular value decomposition?

Tags: cuda, linear-algebra, svd

I am writing some CUDA code for finding the **3** parameters of a circle (centre X,Y & radius) from many (**m**) measurements of positions around the perimeter.
As **m > 3** I am (successfully) using Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) for this purpose (using the cuSolver library). Effectively I am solving **m** simulaneous equations with **3** unknowns.

However, not all of my perimeter positions are valid (say **q** of them), and so I have to go through my initial set of **m** measurements and remove the **q** invalid ones. This involves moving the size **m** data array from the card to the host, processing linearly to remove the **q** invalid entries and then re loading the smaller (**m-q**) array back onto the card...

My question is; if I were to set *all terms* on *both sides* of the **q** invalid equations to *zero*, could I just run the **m** equations (including the zeros) through my SVD analysis (without the data transfer etc) or would this cause other problems?

My instinct tells me that this is a bit like applying weights to the data but instinct and SVD are not terms that sit well together in my experience...

I am hesitant just to try this as I don't know if it will work in some cases and not in others...

Comment: I am struggling to understand what this question really is -- a mathematical question? an algorithmic question about CUSolver internals? Something else?

Comment: The question is about the practical application of the use of SVD routines to solve multiple simultaneous equations.  I am currently writing code to test my ideas (of zeroing both sides of the equations). I have asked the question so that anyone who has experience with this sort of problem can tell me if this is a really bad idea (or not) or even if there are any pitfalls with this approach that I need to look out for.  I used the CUDA flag because there might be implementation-specific issues that I need to be aware of.  I will report back on the results of my testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested the idea by inserting rows of zeros into my matrix.  The solution that I am getting is not significantly affected by this.
So I am answering my own question with a non-rigorous Yes it is OK do do this.

If anybody has a more rigorous or more considered answer I would very much like to hear it.